Ebeans not generating tables in localhosted MySQL File
I'm developing a Minecraft PaperMC plugin using Ebean ORM (v15.1.1) with a MySQL database and IntelliJ for development. However, I keep encountering the following error:
What I’m trying to achieve:
I’m attempting to create a table called players automatically when the plugin is enabled. The table should have columns for a player's UUID, rank, expiry date, etc. The table creation should happen via Ebean’s DDL generation.
What I’ve tried so far:
The exception:
    [12:58:58 ERROR]: [io.ebean.core] Configured to run DDL but ebean-ddl-generator is not in the classpath (or ebean-test in the test classpath?)
[12:58:58 INFO]: [io.ebean.core] Started database[db] platform[MYSQL55] in 4ms
[12:58:58 INFO]: [PlayLegendBewerbung] Successfully created database
[12:58:58 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling PlayLegendBewerbung v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Error: Table 'database.players' doesn't exist
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebean.config.dbplatform.SqlCodeTranslator.translate(SqlCodeTranslator.java:85) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebean.config.dbplatform.DatabasePlatform.translate(DatabasePlatform.java:212) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:77) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.insert(DmlBeanPersister.java:46) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeInsert(PersistRequestBean.java:1064) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNow(PersistRequestBean.java:624) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNoBatch(PersistRequestBean.java:668) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestBean.java:659) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:284) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:234) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.save(DefaultPersister.java:215) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1503) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1495) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/com.carinaschoppe.playLegendBewerbung.database.PlayerDAO.savePlayer(PlayerDAO.java:29) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/com.carinaschoppe.playLegendBewerbung.PlayLegendBewerbung.doDatabaseStuff(PlayLegendBewerbung.java:55) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/com.carinaschoppe.playLegendBewerbung.PlayLegendBewerbung.onEnable(PlayLegendBewerbung.java:40) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:288) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.enablePlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:202) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-57-b483da4]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.enablePlugin(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:109) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-57-b483da4]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:520) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:640) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-57-b483da4]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:589) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-57-b483da4]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld0(MinecraftServer.java:754) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-57-b483da4]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadLevel(MinecraftServer.java:516) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-57-b483da4]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:329) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-57-b483da4]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1215) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-57-b483da4]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:330) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-57-b483da4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'database.players' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:112) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:113) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:938) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1106) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1045) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1369) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1030) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebean.datasource.pool.ExtendedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ExtendedPreparedStatement.java:123) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.bind.DataBind.executeUpdate(DataBind.java:102) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.InsertHandler.execute(InsertHandler.java:105) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlHandler.executeNoBatch(DmlHandler.java:88) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    at PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar/io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:69) ~[PlayLegendBewerbung-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1725620316623.jar:?]
    ... 25 more
[12:58:58 INFO]: [PlayLegendBewerbung] Disabling PlayLegendBewerbung v1.0-SNAPSHOT
[12:58:58 INFO]: [PlayLegendBewerbung] Plugin deaktiviert.
[12:58:58 INFO]: [spark] Starting background profiler...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'database.players' doesn't exist

How I create my Database:
 private Database createDatabase() {

    // Speichern des ursprünglichen ClassLoaders
    ClassLoader originalClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    ClassLoader pluginClassLoader = PlayLegendBewerbung.class.getClassLoader();

    try {
        // Setze den Plugin-ClassLoader als den aktuellen ContextClassLoader
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(pluginClassLoader);

        // Erstelle die Ebean-Datenbank-Konfiguration
        io.ebean.config.DatabaseConfig serverConfig = new io.ebean.config.DatabaseConfig();
        serverConfig.setName("db");
        serverConfig.loadFromProperties();  // Lädt Konfiguration aus application.yaml oder ebean.properties
        serverConfig.setDdlGenerate(true);  // Generiert die Tabellen-SQL-Anweisungen
        serverConfig.setDdlRun(true);       // Führe die DDL aus, um die Tabellen zu erstellen
        serverConfig.setDefaultServer(true);
        serverConfig.setRegister(true);

        // Setze die Datenbankverbindung
        DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig = new DataSourceConfig();
        dataSourceConfig.setUsername("root");  // Setze falls erforderlich
        dataSourceConfig.setPassword("");  // Setze falls erforderlich
        dataSourceConfig.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database");  // SQLite-Dateipfad
        dataSourceConfig.setDriver("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        serverConfig.setDataSourceConfig(dataSourceConfig);
        // Initialisiere alle Klassen, die mit Ebean verbunden sind
        DatabasePlayer.init();  // Initialisiere die DatabasePlayer-Entität
        PlayerDAO.init();  // Initialisiere die DAO für Player

        // Erstelle die Datenbank mit dem Plugin-ClassLoader
        DatabaseFactory.createWithContextClassLoader(serverConfig, pluginClassLoader);
         database = DatabaseFactory.create(serverConfig);


        // Logge die erfolgreiche Erstellung der Datenbank
        this.getLogger().info("Successfully created database");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.getLogger().severe("Error creating database: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Setze den originalen ClassLoader zurück, nachdem die Datenbank initialisiert wurde
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalClassLoader);
    }

    return database;
}

My Table Class:
    package com.carinaschoppe.playLegendBewerbung.database;
 
import io.ebean.Model;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
 
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;
 
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DatabasePlayer extends Model {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID uuid;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rank_name")
    private Rank rank;
    public static void init(){}
    @Column(name = "rank_expiry")
    private LocalDateTime rankExpiry;
 
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
 
    @Column(name = "permanent", nullable = false)
    private boolean permanent;
 
}
 
package com.carinaschoppe.playLegendBewerbung.database;
 
import io.ebean.DB;
import io.ebean.Database;
import io.ebean.Query;
import io.ebean.annotation.Transactional;
 
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
 
@Singleton
public class PlayerDAO {
    public static void init(){}
    private final Database database;
 
    public PlayerDAO(Database database) {
        this.database = database;
    }
 
    /**
     * Speichert oder aktualisiert einen Spieler in der Datenbank.
     *
     * @param databasePlayer Das zu speichernde Player-Objekt.
     */
    @Transactional
    public void savePlayer(DatabasePlayer databasePlayer) {
        database.save(databasePlayer);  // Automatisch speichern oder aktualisieren
    }
 
    /**
     * Holt einen Spieler anhand seiner UUID aus der Datenbank.
     *
     * @param uuid Die UUID des Spielers.
     * @return Der Spieler mit der angegebenen UUID oder null, falls nicht gefunden.
     */
    @Transactional
 
    public Optional<DatabasePlayer> getPlayerByUUID(UUID uuid) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(database.find(DatabasePlayer.class, uuid));
    }
 
    /**
     * Holt alle Spieler aus der Datenbank.
     *
     * @return Eine Liste aller Spieler.
     */
    @Transactional
    public List<DatabasePlayer> getAllPlayers() {
        // Erstellen einer Ebean-Abfrage, um alle Spieler abzurufen
        Query<DatabasePlayer> query = database.find(DatabasePlayer.class);
 
        // Abfrage ausführen und Liste der Spieler zurückgeben
        return query.findList();
    }
 
    public List<DatabasePlayer> findPlayersByName(String name) {
        Query<DatabasePlayer> query = database.find(DatabasePlayer.class).where().eq("name", name).query();
        return query.findList();
    }
 
    public void updatePlayer(DatabasePlayer player) {
        database.update(player);
    }
 
    // Spieler löschen
    public void deletePlayer(DatabasePlayer player) {
        database.delete(player);
    }
}

my Application File:
  # Name der Standarddatenbank
  db:
    # Datenquelle konfigurieren
    datasource:
      username: root   # Benutzername für die Datenbank
      password: ""     # Passwort für die Datenbank (leer lassen, falls nicht erforderlich)
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database  # URL der MySQL-Datenbank
      driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver  # JDBC-Treiber für MySQL
 
    # Automatische Generierung und Ausführung von DDL (Tabellenerstellung)
    ddl:
      generate: true   # Automatisch DDL (Tabellen) generieren
      run: true        # DDL beim Starten ausführen (Tabellen erstellen)
 
    # Debug-Einstellungen, um die ausgeführten SQL-Befehle zu sehen
    debug:
      sql: true        # SQL-Befehle in den Logs anzeigen
 
    # Weitere Datenbankeinstellungen (optional)
    # minConnections: 2
    # maxConnections: 100
    # isolationLevel: READ_COMMITTED

code here

